# How can i set column names on near the boxes in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, statistics, heatmap

I am trying to create a heat map like this
[image: MAP]

My data set is here:[DATASET](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jmXla.png)

```
ggplot(data=mxdf)+
  geom_tile(aes(x=mxdf$Var1,y=mxdf$Var2,fill=mxdf$value))+
  scale_fill_viridis(option = "B",discrete = T,end=1)+
  labs(title = "CORRELATIONS",y="",x="")+
  theme(legend.position = "none",axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, vjust = 1, 
                                                            size = 9, hjust = 1))
```

I use this code and I get this map
[image]

that's okay but X axis column names is too far to graph. How can I set x axis column names like first graph ?

Comment: Please include your data as text (use `dput`) rather than as an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to add `annotate`. However to fix the annotation position you also need to use expansion in the x-axis.

```
 ggplot(data= mxdf)+
  geom_tile(aes(x= mxdf$Var2,y= mxdf$Var1,fill= mxdf$value))+
  scale_fill_viridis(option = "B",discrete = T,end=1)+
  labs(title = "CORRELATIONS",y="",x="")+
  theme(legend.position = "none",axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, vjust = 1, 
                                                            size = 9, hjust = 1)) +
  scale_x_discrete(expand = c(0.5, 0.5)) +
  annotate("text", x = (1:length(levels(mxdf$Var2)))-1, y = 1:length(levels(mxdf$Var2)), label = levels(mxdf$Var2)) +
  theme(
    axis.text.y = element_blank()
  )
```